# Can I error if my bazel target generates files that aren't specified in its outs?

Tags: bazel, build-rules

Inside a `.bzl` file,
I specify a program to generate some code.
It looks something like this:

```
def generate_code():
    native.genrule(
        name = "foo",
        outs = ["file.hpp"],
        tools = ["//path/to:tool"],
        cmd = $(location path/to:tool) $(@D)
    )
```

This works fine,
however the problem is that the tool might generate more files than are specified in `outs`.
I'm trying to find a way to either have bazel stop the build if more files are generated than specified, or to have the outs automatically be everything generated.

Comment: Did you try this and see that bazel doesn’t error out?

Comment: yeah, if `$(location path/to:tool) $(@D)` generates `file1.hpp` and `file2.hpp`, but I only specify `file1.hpp` in my `outs` list, then only `file1.hpp` is transfered to `bazel-gen` and `file2.hpp` gets lost in translation.  Obviously, I find out its missing if other rules need to use the file, but I was hoping bazel would know everything the tool generates and error/warn if something was generated into `$(@D)`, but unspecified as an out.

Comment: Does this also happen in a "full fledged" rule? I think it doesn't but couldn't find the time to validate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a generalized way to have bazel error out if additional, unexpected files were generated.

One thing I could recommend is wrapping your tool in another tool which verifies the output files in the target directory and only returns success if no unexpected files were generated.

As for a generalized solution that intentionally includes *all* files in an output directory, consider using [actions.declare_directory](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/actions.html#declare_directory) and creating a skylark rule instead of using `native.genrule`.